# Pulumi and GCP Uptime Checks deployments failing from time to time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, pulumi

We added recently GCP UptimeChecks to our pulumi stack, we create the uptime check like this

```
ucc, err := monitoring.NewUptimeCheckConfig(ctx, name, &monitoring.UptimeCheckConfigArgs{
        DisplayName: pulumi.String("uptime check example"),
        HttpCheck: &monitoring.UptimeCheckConfigHttpCheckArgs{
            Path:          pulumi.String(fmt.Sprintf("/%s/status", "github")),
            Port:          pulumi.Int(443),
            RequestMethod: pulumi.String("GET"),
            UseSsl:        pulumi.Bool(true),
            ValidateSsl:   pulumi.Bool(true),
        },
        MonitoredResource: &monitoring.UptimeCheckConfigMonitoredResourceArgs{
            Labels: pulumi.StringMap{
                "host": pulumi.String(targetUrl),
            },
            Type: pulumi.String("uptime_url"),
        },
        Period:  pulumi.String("60s"),
        Timeout: pulumi.String("10s"),
    })
```

Then I decided to add an alert policy for this uptime check

**Note**: here we forward the uptime check created previously

```
args := monitoring.AlertPolicyArgs{
        DisplayName: pulumi.String(name),
        Combiner:    pulumi.String("AND"),
        Conditions: monitoring.AlertPolicyConditionArray{
            monitoring.AlertPolicyConditionArgs{
                DisplayName: pulumi.String("Health check alerts for github %s", service.ShortName),
                ConditionThreshold: monitoring.AlertPolicyConditionConditionThresholdArgs{
                    Filter:   pulumi.Sprintf("metric.type=\"monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed\" AND metric.label.check_id=\"%s\" AND resource.type=\"uptime_url\"", uptimeCheck.UptimeCheckId),
                    Duration: pulumi.String("60s"),
                    Trigger: monitoring.AlertPolicyConditionConditionThresholdTriggerArgs{
                        Count: pulumi.IntPtr(1),
                    },
                    ThresholdValue: pulumi.Float64Ptr(1),
                    Comparison:     pulumi.String("COMPARISON_LT"),
                    Aggregations: monitoring.AlertPolicyConditionConditionThresholdAggregationArray{
                        monitoring.AlertPolicyConditionConditionThresholdAggregationArgs{
                            AlignmentPeriod:  pulumi.String("60s"),
                            PerSeriesAligner: pulumi.String("ALIGN_COUNT_TRUE"),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        }
        NotificationChannels: "alerts",
```

This worked fine in the first deployment, but the subsequent ones started to fail.

```
error: deleting urn:pulumi:env::company::gcp:monitoring/uptimeCheckConfig:UptimeCheckConfig::uptime-check-github: 1 error occurred:
Error when reading or editing UptimeCheckConfig: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

**Observed behavior**

What a noticed is the new uptime checks got created in our account, but GCP entered in some weird state where it could not delete the previous uptime check,
the only way I managed to fix the stack was by deleting the old uptime checks manually.

Anyone experienced that?

Answer (score 0):

Just experienced the same. However, I did not need to delete, I could also just slightly modify and save the checks. Afterwards it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a projectId in in monitoredResource.labels
An uptime check monitored resources requires all labels that the type expects
You have used uptime_url so...
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_uptime_url

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).